# Spring Security for RESTful webservice

Tags: spring, rest, security

I am developing a RESTful web service as a back-end layer for mobile application. This service receives combination of device id (as user id) an a pin (as password), and passes to another back-end service, that validates and returns the status of successful login along the user information, in case, the user is authorized. My service is not validating the user. And mobile sends sub sequent requests to my RESTful service.

So, please suggest, how can I make all this system(especially the RESTful) secured, using Spring security.

I am using a Tomcat server, Spring and Jersey

Answer (score 0):

I recently implemented a method to secure my existing RESTful APIs in Spring. I have used a token based authentication model using OAuth2. In my project, I wanted to secure my API's in a way that every request is individually authenticated and authorised based on the token present in the header. If this is something you are looking for, then I would highly recommend you to take a look at the documentation [here](http://projects.spring.io/spring-security-oauth/docs/oauth2.html). If there is anything you are stuck at while implementing it. Please do let me know.

Also, you can find multiple projects for Spring and OAuth [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth)